# airflow: templated argument with BigQueryCheckOperator

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I would like to use the `BigQueryCheckOperator` in airflow where the query needs to have the execution date as parameter. I have written the following operator that check the current date, but I do not understand how to use the `execution_date` of the dag.

```
BigQueryCheckOperator(
        task_id='mytask',
        retry_delay=10,
        retries=2,
        sql="""
           SELECT
            COUNT(*)
           FROM
            mydataset.mytable AS tb
           WHERE
            DATE(tb.date) = '{check_date}'
        """.format(
            check_date=(datetime.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        ),
        bigquery_conn_id='my_google_cloud_conn',
        dag=dag)
```

Could you help me?

Comment: do you want check_date to be execution_date ?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jinja template and variable = {{ ds }}

```
BigQueryCheckOperator(
        task_id='mytask',
        retry_delay=10,
        retries=2,
        sql="""
           SELECT
            COUNT(*)
           FROM
            mydataset.mytable AS tb
           WHERE
            DATE(tb.date) = DATE('{{ ds }}')""",
        bigquery_conn_id='my_google_cloud_conn',
        dag=dag)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I Had to modify it a bit to `DATE('{{ ds }}')` otherwise it wasn't recognized as a date